# Nested for loop in descending order - Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I managed to get the output to almost get what I want but I am not sure what needs to be modified to make the value in the middle to be x.

```
98765
87654
76543
65432
54321
```

The above is the output I got but I want it to display

```
98765
87654
76x43
65432
54321
```

Here is the code

```
for(int row=9;row>=5; row--) {
    for(int col = row; col >=(row + 1 - 5); col--) {
        System.out.printf("%d",col);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could fix my code or at least tell me what to edit to get that output.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if statement inside your loop:

```
for (int row = 9; row >= 5; row--) {
    for (int col = row; col >= (row - 4); col--) {
        if(row == 7 && col == 5) {
            System.out.print("x");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d", col);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```